# Split fixed length string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to split a string in sql server and insert the data in a table.
Te string is fixed length, no comma separated. In the string I can have 1 or more records to insert, for example:

id = 2 characters
name = 4 characters

string: `01AAAA02BBBB03CCCC`.

In this example I have 3 records to insert (I can have only one record or more in the string)

id  Name
   01  AAAA
   02  BBBB
   03  CCCC

I need a way to split this info in two different columns and in three different rows. I was thinking to use BCP utility but I'm not sure, maybe I need to split and generate a file and then use BCP.

Any idea?

Comment: How can you have one or more records if the string is fixed length? Is it padded with spaces? What is the string length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will handle more than 3 id/name pairs. Note however, that there is no error checking. I leave that to you.

```
DECLARE @Input NVARCHAR(18)
SET @Input = '01AAAA02BBBB03CCCC'

DECLARE @Data TABLE 
(
    [Id] NCHAR(2),
    [Name] NCHAR(4)
)

WHILE LEN(@Input) > 0
BEGIN

    DECLARE @CurrentData NCHAR(6)
    SET @CurrentData = LEFT(@Input, 6)  

    DECLARE @CurrentId NCHAR(2)
    SET @CurrentId = LEFT(@CurrentData, 2)  

    DECLARE @CurrentName NCHAR(4)
    SET @CurrentName = RIGHT(@CurrentData, 4)   

    INSERT INTO @Data
    (
        [Id],
        [Name]
    )
    SELECT
        @CurrentId,
        @CurrentName

    SET @Input = RIGHT(@Input, LEN(@Input) - 6)

END

SELECT 
    [Id],
    [Name]
FROM
    @Data
```

Comment: HI seth flowers, I like the idea, I created a query with the list of string, if I need to apply your solution, should I create a function and call the function for each row and do the inserts? or there is another way to do it directly? thanks

Comment: It depends on the situation, and without knowing more about it, it's hard for me to say. You could create a function to just return the table variable, if you need this data split from more than one place in your database. You could then use the data in the table variable however you see fit.

Comment: I'm going to build an sp for the previous code, thank you very much to all of you!!!!!

Comment: I have an error for example if I have this   string '01AAAA02BBBB03CCCC      ' with spaces at the end I should take in count that maybe I'm going to have spaces in the beginning and also at the end

Comment: I know the problem is the LEN() function, but if I use DATALENGTH is worse, is double the len....

Comment: I fixed, I replaced SET @Input = RIGHT(@Input, LEN(@Input) - 6) by STUFF function thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Since the string is always of fixed length, then you can do this:

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(50) = '01AAAA02BBBB03CCCC';

SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@s, 01, 2) AS ID,  SUBSTRING(@s, 3, 4) AS Name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@s, 7, 2) AS ID,  SUBSTRING(@s, 9, 4) AS Name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@s, 13, 2) AS ID,  SUBSTRING(@s, 15, 4) AS Name
) t;
```

This will give you:

```
ID  Name
01  AAAA
02  BBBB
03  CCCC
```

**Update:** If you want to get this string from a column of a table, you can do this:

```
DECLARE @t table(name varchar(50));
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('01AAAA02BBBB03CCCC'),
('01DDDD02BBBB03CCCC'),
('01HHHH02QQQQ03CCCC'),
('01IIII02MMMM03CCCC');

SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT SUBSTRING(name, 1, 2) AS ID,  SUBSTRING(name, 3, 4) AS Name
    FROM @t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SUBSTRING(name, 7, 2) AS ID,  SUBSTRING(name, 9, 4) AS Name
    FROM @t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SUBSTRING(name, 13, 2) AS ID,  SUBSTRING(name, 15, 4) AS Name
    FROM @t
) t;
```

This will give you the following:

```
ID  Name
01  AAAA
01  DDDD
01  HHHH
01  IIII
02  BBBB
02  BBBB
02  QQQQ
02  MMMM
03  CCCC
03  CCCC
03  CCCC
03  CCCC
```

Comment: Ok thank you! I undestand, but what about taking the column from a real query? and besides, I don't know how many records I will have in the string

Comment: @rgx71 You can replace `@s` from the column name from the table, see my edit. I updated my answer shown you how to do this.